# How to get data from netCDF in python?

Tags: python, netcdf4

I have a .nc file (NASA Ocean colour level-3 binned chlor_a data, to be precise). I wish to extract the data from it. I was instructed on the official forum to use netCDF4 module.

Using

`nc.groups['level-3_binned_data'].variables['chlor_a']`

I get this:

`<class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'> compound chlor_a(binDataDim) compound data type: {'names':['sum','sum_squared'], 'formats':['<f4','<f4'], 'offsets':[0,4], 'itemsize':8, 'aligned':True} path = /level-3_binned_data unlimited dimensions: binDataDim current shape = (31749,)`

I wish to see the values of *sum* and *sum_squared*.

How do I go about this? Any help or tips are appreciated!   :)

Comment: Can you link me to the data set that you're trying to access? Is this something you still need help with? I am happy to assist.

Comment: [NASA](https://oceancolor.gsfc.nasa.gov/l3/order/) I if may bother you with this: pick any product on any given day for any location, and make sure you tick the "Binned" box. I don't know if there is a more direct way of sending the data. Thanks!